# php sort mutidimensional array by column name

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
data = [{id: 1, total: 400},{id: 2, total: 100},{id: 3, total: 500},{id: 4, total: 10}]
```

How can I sort that array by total? Also I've tried to get the field total but I failed.

```
foreach($data as $val){
  $d[] = $val['total'];
}
return $d;
```

And got this error.

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: http://brianhaveri.github.io/Underscore.php/ can do that for you.

Comment: why you dont do this in your query ?

Comment: @Monty, I already did but I'm merging from 2 arrays so the final array is not sorted.

Comment: show me query with sample data i will optimize

Comment: here's the data.. I'm using laravel 4.2 
https://gist.github.com/cptsky/b10be56a20966359b42b

Answer (score 2):

Try a `usort`: If you are still on PHP 5.2 or earlier, you'll have to define a sorting function first:

```
$json = '[{"id": 1, "total": 400}, {"id": 2, "total": 100}, {"id": 3, "total": 500}, {"id": 4, "total": 10}]';

    $myArray = json_decode($json, true);
    function sortByOrder($a, $b)
    {
        return $a['total'] - $b['total'];
    }

    usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
    print_r($myArray);
```

Starting in PHP 5.3, you can use an anonymous function:

```
usort($myArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['total'] - $b['total'];
});
```

And finally with PHP 7 you can use the "spaceship operator":

```
usort($myArray, function ($a, $b) {
        return $a['type'] <=> $b['type'];
});
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [total] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [total] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [total] => 400
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [total] => 500
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Required: Sort the array of objects by the `total` property.

#### code:

```
$json = '[{"id": 1, "total": 400}, {"id": 2, "total": 100}, {"id": 3, "total": 500}, {"id": 4, "total": 10}]';

$data = json_decode($json);

usort($data, function ($t1, $t2) {
        return $t1->total - $t2->total;
    }); 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [total] => 10
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [total] => 100
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [total] => 400
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [total] => 500
        )
)
```

Comment: How can I convert my array from [{id: 1, total: 100}] into [{"id": 1, "total": 100}]?

Comment: @kerwin, how did you generate that string? Where did the data come from that you converted to look like that? The usual way to generate `JSON` strings, in PHP, is to use `json_encode($phpDataItem);` where the `dataItem` is a PHP array, etc.

Comment: I generated the data using laravel query.
here's my code with explaination. https://gist.github.com/cptsky/b10be56a20966359b42b

Comment: @Kerwin, Ok, There are various directions we can go from here 1) Get the SQL to do more work to help to get the data you want and in the correct order. 2) I assume `$val` holds the array you want sorted. If you `var_dump($val);` you should see how to sort it. Or, Given the queries you have already created. They could be combined with a _`union`_ and the _`sum`_ with a  _`group by`_. Apply an `order by` as well and It should return the array how you want it.